# How to do Mongoose Queries in Keystonejs 5

Tags: keystonejs

Have im new to keystonejs 5 and this new graphql thing with the latest version. 
In previous Keystone 4 i was able to retrieve data by using something like this `.list('users')`

In this new version im really confused on how we can do simple mongoose queries.

If anyone can guide me on how to query like old keystone versions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

`User.adapter.find({ isModerator: true })`

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)